# c++ 3d array function returns

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, return-type

So i've got this 3 dimensional array that looks like this:

`int map[100][100][100];`

and I want to use it as a return type for a function, whether as a pointer or whatever like so:

```
int* World::CreateCell() {

    int map[100][100][100];

    return map;

}
```

However I cannot find the appropriate return type for a 3d array, it will not let me use an int* like you can for a 2D array.

Even things like this don't work:

```
int a[100][100][100];
int* b = a;
```

VS seems to think the data type is `int*(100)(100)` but that makes no sense and doesn't work.

For what it's worth, I've googled this and seen no solutions. Thank you

Comment: you are on the wrong track. Returning a pointer to a local array would be wrong also with a 2d array. Use nested `std::array` or `std::vector` instead

Comment: In C++ you should in general NOT use C-Style arrays. There is no reason for it. If you follow this rule then most of such problems are gone . . .

Comment: i got you bros, sorted it with nested vectors

Comment: Just for the record: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98bcbe553a104926).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want 3D C-style array, you need to have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, i.e., `int***`. Also, you need to allocate the memory if you use a creation function like this. Otherwise, you return the statically allocated memory from that function.

Here is a quick example of how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

static int*** create_cell() {    
    constexpr std::size_t n = 100;
    int*** map = new int**[n];
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        map[i] = new int*[n];
        for (std::size_t j = 0u; j < n; ++j) {    
            map[i][j] = new int[n];
        }
    }   
    return map;
}

static void delete_cell(int***& map) { 
    constexpr std::size_t n = 100;
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0u; j < n; ++j) {    
            delete[] map[i][j];
        }
        delete[] map[i];
    }
    delete[] map;    
}

int main()
{
    int*** a = create_cell();

    a[0][0][0] = 1;
    std::cout << "a[0][0][0] = " << a[0][0][0] << std::endl;
    
    delete_cell(a);

    return 0;
}
```

It depends on your use case: BUT for modern c++ you can ease your life using containers from the `stl` such as `std::vector` and `std::array`. Check here for reference: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

For example, you can define your 3D types:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using vector_3d = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;
using array_3d = std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100>, 100>;
```

and then use them as:

```
array_3d b;
b[0][0][0] = 1;
std::cout << "b[0][0][0] = " << b[0][0][0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should

> Never return a reference or a pointer to a local non-static variable.

Now coming to your question:

> I want to use it as a return type for a function, whether as a pointer or whatever like so.However I cannot find the appropriate return type for a 3d array.

This(below) is how you can do it for a 3D array. Basically there are **2 ways** to solve this:

**Method 1**

```
//CreateCell is a function that returns a pointer to a 3D array of the size 100,100,100
int (*CreateCell())[100][100][100] {

    int map[100][100][100];

    return &map;
}
```

Method 1 works as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WSrPUpNRQmEGAxUl).

**Method 2**

```
//CreateCell is a function that returns a pointer to a 3D array of the size 100,100,100
auto CreateCell() -> int(*)[100][100][100] {

    int map[100][100][100];

    return &map;
}
```

Method 2 uses **trailing return type** and works as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zy3LkpxsjhmhindX).

### Note

Both methods return a pointer to a local variable which must be avoided. I have given/written the answer just so that you can see how to return a pointer for a 3D array as you desired. You can instead create and return a 3D `std::vector` by value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a simple wrapper around your matrix:

```
struct Wrapper { int Mat[100][100][100] = {0}; };
```

The signature would then become something like:

```
Wrapper *foo(...) { ... }
```

Here is simple working example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Wrapper { int Mat[100][100][100] = {0}; };
Wrapper *inc(Wrapper *w)
{
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<100;j++)
            for (int k=0;k<100;k++)
                w->Mat[i][j][k] += (i+j+k);
    return w;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Wrapper w;
    Wrapper *out = inc(&w);
    std::cout << out->Mat[5][6][7] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```